# Como pôr sub menus descendo centrados com menus

Tags: css-centering

Como pôr sub menus descendo centrados com menus? www.festasparapalmoemeio.pt

Esta é a minha 1º pergunta, pois estou mesmo precisando de uma resposta que me ajude a conseguir o que pretendo.

Pretende-se que cada sub menu desça na horizontal, exactamente debaixo e ao centro do respectivo menu.

Neste momento os sub menus estão abrindo/descendo para a direita dos menus. :(

Peço ajuda aqui em último recurso, após várias pesquisas e múltiplas tentativas que não surtiram o efeito pretendido.

Espero então por alguém que me posso ajudar. Entretanto, mesmo cansado e desesperado, vou continuar procurando e tentando.

Comment: Por favor adicione um exemplo de código na própria pergunta para que os outros possam reproduzir o problema. Linkar para o seu site não é legal, pois em breve ele estará consertado e a pergunta perderá o sentido. O objetivo do site é ter perguntas e respostas que sirvam também para outros usuários no futuro. Para dicas sobre como criar um exemplo, ver [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) na [Central de ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

coloque nas suas sub ULs isso: `margin-left: -50px;` a ajuste esse 50 em cada de forma que fique centralizada